# Discord.py bot can't read my messages except if mention is included

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

So, my bot was working normally umtil this happened. It didn't respond to my commands so i decided to put `print(msg.content)` in order to find out what's wrong. The result was to print an empty message when i typed something, except if <@its_id> was included. This is the code. Any help is welcome.

```
import os, discord, random, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
from replit import db

PREFIX = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=discord.Intents.default())
INVITE_LINK = 'url'
app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return 'Bot is ready!'

def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target=run)
  server.start()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  activity = discord.Game(name="!help", type=3)
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
  print('Ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
  print(msg.content)
  ...

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['bot_token'])
#discord.errors.HTTPException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is your intents. Try changing your intents from `discord.Intents.default()` to `discord.Intents.all()` and make sure your bot has the appropriate permission in the discord developer portal.